# sed: Match two strings in a file

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to remove lines from a file that start with `[0]` or `[33]`

`sed -i '/(\[0\]|\[33\])/d' file.txt`

doesn't seem to do the trick though. What am I missing?

Comment: `sed 's/^\(0\|33\)//g' file.txt`

Comment: You need to escape the pipe, the parenthesis and to add an anchor: `sed -i '/^\(\[0\]\|\[33\]\)/d' file.txt` or better: `sed -i '/^\[\(0\|33\)\]/d' file.txt`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks yours worked! Can you make it an answer so I can upvote

Comment: @Avinash Because I'm a true noob and don't understand the benefits other than "it works"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just print the lines which isn't starts with `[0]` or `[33]`,

```
sed -nr '/^\[(0|33)\]/!p' file
```

To save the changes the you need to add inline-edit `-i` option.

```
sed -nri '/^\[(0|33)\]/!p' file
```

Comment: then it would be `sed -nri '/^\[(0|33)\]/!p' file`